# Application crash when tap for 1-2 seconds on Edittextview

Tags: java, android

I am implementing Login activity.
When I tap for 1-3 seconds on User Id field that is EditText then error shown like 'Unfortunately,app has stopped.'
I got this error for MOTO G 2nd gen..
Is there any issue of version??
Plz help me.
And error is:

```
04-13 16:29:30.420: E/InputEventReceiver(19679): Exception dispatching input event.
04-13 16:29:30.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getActionBarThemedContext(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:208)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:195)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:359)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2780)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2729)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:812)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:812)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:812)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:5338)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.widget.Editor.startInsertionActionMode(Editor.java:1725)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8324)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9297)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2769)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9517)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4242)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4108)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3799)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3856)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5969)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5869)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6072)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-13 16:29:30.465: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19679):  at android.app.ActivityT
04-13 16:29:30.465: D/AndroidRuntime(19679): Shutting down VM
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679): Process: com.code.homeopathyapp, PID: 19679
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getActionBarThemedContext(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:208)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:195)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:359)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2780)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2729)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:812)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:812)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:812)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:5338)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.widget.Editor.startInsertionActionMode(Editor.java:1725)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8324)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9297)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2769)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9517)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4242)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4108)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3799)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3856)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5969)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5869)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6072)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
04-13 16:29:30.466: E/AndroidRuntime(19679):    at a
```

Comment: What you have done? Please show that code.

Comment: there might be something related to lingpressed event

Comment: I dont get this error so I dono from which activity shows this. Plz give me suggations..

Comment: try by changing ActionBarActivity to Activity